# How can I test my typescript function on angular to improve my coverage

Tags: angular

Hi so I have this function that gets called on click:

```
toogleTag() 

{
    this.truthOrFalse = !this.truthOrFalse;

    if (this.truthOrFalse) {
      this.showme = true;
      this.fraisAdministrationEditer = true;
      this.autreMentionEditer = true;
      this.tauxAdditionnelFADQEditer = true;
      this.sendInfoToggleService.editerReadOnly = true;
    } else {
      this.showme = false;
      this.fraisAdministrationEditer = false;
      this.autreMentionEditer = false;
      this.tauxAdditionnelFADQEditer = false;
      this.sendInfoToggleService.editerReadOnly = false;
    }`

I tried testing it using this:
it('devrait appeler la fonction truthToggle 2 fois et valider les booleans', fakeAsync(() => {
    spyOn(component, 'toogleTag');

    const button = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('.slider');
    button.click();
    tick();

    expect(component.toogleTag).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(component.toogleTag).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);

    expect(component.truthOrFalse).toBeFalsy();
    expect(component.fraisAdministrationEditer).toBeFalsy();
    expect(component.autreMentionEditer).toBeFalsy();
    expect(component.tauxAdditionnelFADQEditer).toBeFalsy();
    expect(component.showme).toBeFalsy();

  }));
```

However it seems like it does not cover my if else at all. Would anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not going into the `else`?

I assume your `truthOrFalse` property is initialised (or not) as false (or undefined).

You're only clicking your toggle button the once in that test, so setting it to true.

Surely you'd need to click it again to then set it false?

```
// initially false or undefined

button.click();
tick(); // true

// test here for the if/true changes

button.click();
tick(); // false

// Test here for the else/false changes
```